# How to remove values from a map in Terraform that match a list of keys?

Tags: terraform

I want to remove values from a map in Terraform that match a list of keys e.g. remove keys_b and keys_c from the map below.

Input

```
map = {
  key_a = value_a,
  key_b = value_b,
  key_c = value_c
  ...
  key_m = value_m
}
```

Desired Output

```
filtered_map  = {
  key_a = value_a,
  ...
  key_m = value_m
}
```

I've tried using the contains function but that passes through only one value and not a list of values. I am not sure how to loop over this either.

```
output "test" {
  value = { for k, v in var.map: k => v if ! contains(values(v), var.exclude) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You had wrong arguments in [contains](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/contains). It should be:

```
output "test" {
  value = { for k, v in var.map: k => v if contains(var.exclude, k) }
}
```